# Add array inside object with same key in jolt spec

Tags: jolt

I would like to move the recommendations array by row_id key inside the investors with the same row_id

Original Json

```
{
  "investors": [
    {
      "row_id": 1,
      "name": "AAAA"
    },
    {
      "row_id": 2,
      "name": "BBBB"
    }
  ],
  "recommendations": [
    {
      "row_id": "1",
      "title": "ABC"
    },
    {
      "row_id": "2",
      "title": "CDE"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried a lot of specs at https://jolt-demo.appspot.com with no success

Specs tried...

```
[{
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "investors": {
      "*": "investors[]"
    },
    "recommendations": {
      "@": "recommendations[]"
    }
  }
}]
```

Desired Json

```
{
  "investors": [
    {
      "row_id": 1,
      "name": "AAAA",
      "recommendations":[{
          "row_id": "1",
          "title": "ABC"   
      }]
    },
    {
      "row_id": 2,
      "name": "BBBB",
      "recommendations":[{
          "row_id": "2",
          "title": "CDE"   
      }]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in two stage shift

First shift groups everything based on row_id.

(I'd suggest running the first shift of its own to see what the output is)

Second shift uses that grouped output and formats results.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "row_id": {
            "*": {
              "@2": "&.&4"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "investors": "investors.[#2]",
        "recommendations": "investors.[#2].recommendations[]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```